# Регулярное выражение для вещественных чисел

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

При составлении регулярки наткнулся на следующую ситуацию
"SELECT '.9' REGEXP '[0-9][0-9.]*" возвращает 1, а не 0, как кажется при поверхностных знаниях REGEXP. Данное выражение я понимаю следующим образом. Регулярка парсится слева направо. У первой квадратной скобки отсутствует квантификатор, т.е. в начале найденного слова должна быть, как минимум, одна цифра". Но ее НЕТ! А результат - 1.
Как поправить выражение, чтобы "ловить" слова типа 2312.; 231425.34543478, 3456
но варианты типа ".9" давали 0? И в чем ошибочность моего понимания парсинга этой регулярки?

Дополнение: Результат возник при использовании
Mysql 5.5
Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: С пониманием и созданием регулярок может очень помочь [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Comment: А вообще вы в какой СУБД тестируете (MySQL, Postgres)? Наверняка у них отличается как-то отличается синтаксис использования регулярок.

Comment: А вы начало строки (`^`) забыли указать. Без него регулярка ищет совпадение "где нибудь в строке", а не обязательно с начала

Comment: 1. Использую MySQL 5.5 под Ubuntu 2. Не указал специально, так как мне надо находить такие слова внутри строк.

Comment: Тогда определитесь, что должно или не должно стоять перед цифрами. например укажите что перед цифрами идет пробел или начало строки (`( |^)`).

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло, но суть проблемы "почему последовательность квадратных скобок" не задает последовательности вариантов символов в регулярке пока от меня ускользает)

Answer (score 1):

Результат 1, потому что выражение ".9" соответствует регулярке "[0-9][0-9.]*".
Давайте, рассмотрим, что вы ищете:

1. должно быть одна цифра от 0 до 9
2. **может** быть символ от 0 до 9 или точка

Первый символ - "." - не соответствует.

Второй символ - "9" - начинаем проверять:
  соответствует первому правилу - цифра 9
  соответствует второму правилу - символа может не быть

Поэтому, результат запроса - 1.

Попробуйте такой шаблон: `"(^| )[0-9](.[0-9]+)*($| )"`

Вместо/вместе с пробелом можно использовать и другие разделители.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ! Но логику регулярок так до конца и не понял. Интуитивно кажется, что последовательное размещение скобок [...][...] без привязки к символу/началу строки подразумевает что первая скобка содержит то, что в найденной последовательности должно идти раньше, а не позже того, что содержится во второй скобке. Т.е. последовательная "трактовка" квадратных скобок в регулярке не выполняется, если в регулярке нет привязки к конкретному символу, или началу,концу строки? Т.е., регулярки [0-9][0-9.]*, [0-9.]*[0-9] идентичны?

Comment: То, что во второй скобке можно игнорировать, т.к. там стоит *. А то, что перед точкой должна быть цифра, на самом деле, не обязательное условие.